# Schedule on and skip login screen

Tags: power-management, pmset

I'm trying to schedule my Mac Mini to automatically turn off at the end of the day and then turn back on the next morning, login, and then run an AppleScript.

This was all working fine in Monterey using power-saving options in the Control Panel. Unfortunately, I stupidly upgraded to Ventura and that option is now gone.

I tried to reproduce the behavior using `pmset`, but it won't automatically log in anymore. I do still have auto login set in the System Settings. Is there something else I might be missing or some other workaround?

Comment: If you manually restart or shut down, does your Mac automatically log-in when next powered on?

Comment: Does your script require a graphical user session (AppleScript, Automator, Shortcut, …) or can it be run from the command line?

Comment: @GrahamMiln a manual restart works fine. The script basically starts playing a video on loop and makes it full screen. It is written in apple script.

Comment: Given the unreliable macOS behaviour, consider a scheduled sleep/wake in combination with [VLC for more reliable looping movie playback](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2014-10-25-reliable-presentation-playback/).